# Receiving No WS-Security Header error when attempting to POST to Cybersource Simple Order API

Tags: soap, cybersource

I am attempting to POST using Postman to the Cybersource Simple Order API, but it comes back with a no header error when doing so. What am I doing wrong here? Since the merchant ID is used as the username, what is used as the password, should this be the Simple Order transaction processing key?

Posting the following XML data to the test endpoint (https://ics2wstesta.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken>
         <wsse:Username>merchantname</wsse:Username>
         <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile1.0#PasswordText">key</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<requestMessage xmlns="urn:schemas-cybersource-com:transaction-data-1.150">
<merchantID>merchantname</merchantID>
<merchantReferenceCode>12345678912</merchantReferenceCode>
<recurringSubscriptionInfo>
<subscriptionID>12345678901234567890</subscriptionID>
</recurringSubscriptionInfo>
<paySubscriptionDeleteService run="true"/>
</requestMessage>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a small error in your namespaces. You missed a "-".

oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext1.0.xsd

should be

oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd

and

oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile1.0#PasswordText

should be

oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText

Comment: Thanks, that changed the error message so it's now coming up with "Security Data : UsernameToken authentication failed". I am using the test account merchant ID as username and the Simple Order key as password.

Comment: The key type should be Transaction Processing: SOAP in the new EBC.